# I will see you when I WAS at home?

Tags: tenses

Is it correct to say "I will see you when I was at home"?

Or "I will see you when I am at home"?

I am a little confused about the thing will happen in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, if you’re Doctor Who.

Comment: @Lawrence I am sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: Doctor Who is a fictional time traveller. So his ‘future’ could be in the observer’s ‘past’.

Comment: Hi Nan, this particular question is trivial for native speakers and such questions are usually off-topic on this site; please consider the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) (ELL) Stack Exchange instead.  In addition, EL&U has a 'research requirement': you are supposed to have attempted to answer the question yourself using commonly available resources and are supposed to summarize this research, explaining why you still don't think you know the answer. The ELL SE also has a research requirement, but it is arguably less strict.

Comment: @linguisticturn Thanks a lot for the reminder. Sorry, I do not know the rules here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely not *was*. But even *when I am at home* does not sound completely idiomatic. We'd rather say something like

[1] *I'll see you when I get home.*

I suppose something like this could work, too:

[2] *I'll see you when I'm back.*

[3] *I'll see you when I'm back home.*